# cordova network connection always return Connection.NONE on Android

Tags: android, cordova, networking, connection, status

In my Cordova app I'm using cordova-plugin-network-information to check if there is internet connection. It works perfectly on iOS, but on Android if I resume the app after some minutes / hours the plugin fail to check the connection status: after working good for several times resuming the app, It suddently returns Connection.NONE == true even if there is internet connection. I try to browse with Chrome, and it works. I close the app and I reopen it, and the connection check verifies the internet connection correctly.

I tried several cordova cli, cordova-android and cordova-plugin-network-information version.

My code is:

```
if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE)
{
    alert("There is not connection")
} 
else 
{
    alert("There is internet connection")
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it by any chance? I'm afraid I encounter the same problem than you! :(

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14132

Comment: For a solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50835842/777265