# cordova-plugin-network-information on android return connection.type = NONE even if there is 4G connection

Tags: android, cordova, connection

There is a problem with Cordova-plugin-network-information on Android. Even if there is a 4G connection, sometimes, when I resume the app from the background and I check connection with navigator.connection.type  it returns connection.type = NONE, but there is an internet connection. If I close and re-open the app it returns connection.type = 4G. I user cordova@7.1.0 and cordova-android@6.4.0

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14132

Answer (score 3):

This is the workaround I'm currently using for this issue:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function(){
    navigator.connection.getInfo(function(type){
        navigator.connection.type = type;
    });
}, false);
```

See [CB-14132](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14132) for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
             if(navigator.onLine) {
                 alert("Internet Connect");
                  }else {
                       alert("No Internet");
                  }
        }
```

Comment: Using `navigator.onLine` will not help while the network information plugin is installed because it [replaces the navigator.onLine property](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/www/network.js#L32)